# a NOT EXISTS query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, not-exists

everyone,I saw this example of 'not exist' query in a class.But I'm really confused.
 it is used to find all students who have taken all courses offered in the Biology department,but I don't see why?Can someone help me?Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4vfb.png)

Comment: Yes the query shows all students that have taken all courses in the Biology department. And your question is, why this query was written?

Comment: You got the point. Yes, my question is why the query is written like this?It seems to be really strange.

Comment: Well, the task is to find students for which **not exists** a missing biology course. So the query writer used `NOT EXISTS`. You may come to a different query by formulating the task differently. How would you write the query?

Answer (score 0):

The 'NOT EXIST' indicates a clause which will be satisfied if the subquery (select T_course_id ...) returns 0 records.

Comment: So the first query was used to refute the subquery "not exist",then why bother do this? Can't we just say "exist" something?

Comment: It depends, perhaps is more easy to do a subquery which exclude some results than one which include all the corrects one. Sometimes it's more easy to use EXIST, some other times NOT EXIST is better.